# mapping_rviz_plugin

Tags: kinect, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Can anyone help me with piano demo kinect? When I try to run rviz, the answer is error: Package [mapping_rviz_plugin] does not Have Any loaded plugins available, for display of type [mapping_rviz_plugin:: PolygonalMapDisplay] and name [PolygonalMap3]
I can not find this plugin, someone could tell me how to install it?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11593/mapping_rviz_plugin/) by [snoworld](https://answers.ros.org/users/268/snoworld/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question was also asked here: http://answers.ros.org/question/1119/polygonal-map-not-working-in-rviz

"rosmake mapping_rviz_plugin" worked for us as well.

---

Originally posted by [kapy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1414/kapy/) with karma: 16 on 2011-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0